# Why "npm run dev" locks on "ready on localhost" in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem.
I just got a project from TFS.
The code was working properly in my last system and now that I got it from TFS it does not compile.
and stays on " ready on localhost..."
I tried to install next, react and react-dom, but the problem still exists.
can anybody tell me what's wrong in getting the project from TFS?
Should I install any other dependencies for the project or not?
Thanks.

[npm state message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54R90.png)

Comment: So when it is ready, did you try to hit the localhost url?

Comment: Ready on `http://localhost:3001/` means you can hit the URL using your browser.
Type `http://localhost:3001/` in the URL bar in Chrome.

Comment: yes , but nothing happens and for every refresh in browser it just return [event] : build pages/_error

Comment: is it possible to have version conflict in nextjs or react?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
1. delete node modules and packa
3. npm run build
3. you will see webpack error in console
3. npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `npm install` from the Directory to pull down the Node Modules

Comment: Yes i did,but still not working. Is it possible to have version conflict?